# Identical classes with different names

Tags: c#, class

I want to be a little be more descriptive in my class names. I have three identical classes that look like this:

```
    public class Dog   
    {
        public string name;  
        public int id;  

        public Dog(){}
        public Dog(DataRow dr)
        {
            name = dr["Name"];
            id = dr["Id"];
        }   
    }    
    public class Cat
    {
        public string name;  
        public int id;  

        public Cat(){}
        public Cat(DataRow dr)
        {
            name = dr["Name"];
            id = dr["Id"];
        }   
    }
    public class Horse
    {
        public string name;  
        public int horseId;  

        public Horse(){}
        public Horse(DataRow dr)
        {
            name = dr["Name"];
            horseId= dr["horseId"];
        }   
    }
```

How do I avoid code duplication by using a base class? What are the best practicies? pplease note that horse has a property called HorseId instead of Id.  Thanks.

Comment: Make it *not* called `horseId` would be my suggestion :)

Comment: @minitech, yeah, maybe you're right. But then I create a base class and inherit that class? this mean my three classes are going to be empty, right?

Comment: @user194076: how about creating a class "Animal" and passing the animal "type" (presumably enum) by a constructor parameter?

Comment: They could be, but if they're only there as names, then why not just name your variables and use the base class? Or is the situation super-complicated?

Comment: I notice NONE of the answers have yet recommended public properties instead of public fields, nor have they commented on basic coding standards, so none of the current answers will be getting a +1 from me....

Comment: Nothing wrong with public fields for simple objects, @slugster - you can always turn them into properties later if need be.  That's the nice thing about properties - they abstract away the difference.

Comment: -1 for passing a DataRow in the constructor.

Comment: @Jeroen, is it a bad prcatice? What should I do instead?

Comment: Never use public variables. Make public get; set; properties and remove the constructors. Or if you insist on a constructor pass the id and name as parameters, not the DataRow.

Answer (score 3):

Use inheritance.

```
public class Animal 
{
    public string name;  
    public int id;  

    public Animal() {}
    public Animal(DataRow dr)
    {
        name = (string)dr["Name"];
        id = (int)dr["Id"];
    }   
}

// unfortunately, constructors aren't inherited automatically in C#.
public class Cat : Animal 
{
   public Cat() : base() {}
   public Cat(DataRow dr) : base(dr) {}
} 

public class Dog : Animal 
{     
   public Dog() : base() {}
   public Dog(DataRow dr) : base(dr) {}
}

public class Horse: Animal 
{
   public int horseId { get { return id; } set { id = value; } }
   public Horse() : base() {}
   public Horse(DataRow dr) : base(dr) {}    
}
```

**EDIT:** as Blorgbeard says, you can make `Animal` an `abstract` class if you want - that will prevent instantiation (`new Animal()` will be illegal; client code will have to pick a specific subclass).

Answer (score 0):

I would make an interface called `IAnimal` that has properties `name` and `id` and have all 3 classes above implement this interface.  Note is is slightly different than what you have here, as what you have here shows public variables, not public properties.  If you want to maintain variables, then I would use a base class `Animal` with public variables `name` and `id` and convert `horseId` to a property that, interally, gets and sets the base `id` property like this `public int horseId { get { return base.id; } set { base.id = value; } }`

Comment: Of course interfaces can have properties -- they cannot have variables.

Comment: `public interface IAnimal { int id { get; set; } string name { get; set; } }`

Comment: He's asking two things that are possibly conflicting.  My guess is he's new and he's trying to figure out what's what.  I gave two options to tackle this problem -- one is an interface and one is a base class.  He asked "what are the best practices" so I gave him two options.  He also put a special case of horseId, which I also addressed (as did others).  From a purist perspective, in this case an (abstract) base is probably sufficient, as interface `IAnimal` is not describing what it can do, but what characteristics it has.  Still, I don't see why it's so bad showing him two options.

Comment: Looking at the question I think it is safe to assume that `horseId` is a mistake and should actually be `id` like the others. It is uncommon to introduce interfaces on data objects especially when you already have a base class, not to mention interfaces do not in themselves reduce code duplication.

Comment: Read the Q slugster. He made a point to note horseId and that it's different. So no, not a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do something like this - an abstract base class.

```
public abstract class Animal {
   public string name;
   public int id;
   protected Animal() {}
   protected Animal(DataRow dr) {
      name = (string)dr["Name"];
      id = (int)dr["Id"];
   }
}

public class Cat : Animal {
   public Cat() : base() {}
   public Cat(DataRow dr) : base(dr) {}
}
```

Then just add a property to Horse (still leaving `id` as well)

```
public class Horse : Animal {
   public int horseid { get { return id; } set { id = value; } }
   public Horse() : base() {}
   public Horse(DataRow dr) : base(dr) {}
}
```

This method doesn't allow you remove/hide `id` in the `Horse` class, so you will have both `id` and `horseid`, but they will use the same variable underneath.

Answer (score 0):

As far as some good examples on object oriented design, I'd recommend two books.

1. The Object Oriented Thought Process
2. Agile Principles, Patterns and Practices in C# by Robert C. Martin. This book is just awesome at explaining great principles of OOP.